# OpenMage 20.01 - what version of Magento and Supee

Tags: openmage

Just updated to OpenMage LTS 20.0.1.  Having issues with PCI compliance - the scan is showing Magento version 1.9.4.4.

Is this a false positive?
If so is OpenMage LTS 20.0.1 based on 1.9.4.5 + Supee 11346

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Tag 20.0.1 on the OpenMage LTS repository contains the commits

for Supee 11346 https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/commit/e8f43773d69fe1cf6fed5e85b45c1b8332423ec5

and for the update to 1.9.4.5 https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/commit/16dc8f76f1f6bbbaf18005e88ae08df218d60aac

so this is likely a false positive.

Do you find out what they check from the access log?

There may be the possibility, that you have rewrites, or overwrites in app/code/local or your theme, which make the latest patch/release useless.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  I disabled all local overwrites and the scan still shows as 1.9.4.4 (even the Magento Security Scan Tool).  The site does go through a CDN (have tried flushing cache).  However, I checked the commits and the latest supees are applied on my server therefore I argued the case for a false positive.  After a few emails pointing them to the OpenMage closed requests page convinced them the patches were applied https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed